# Implementing intersection operator for a set-like class in Python

Tags: python, set-intersection

I'm trying to implement a wrapper class which should ideally allow me to get the intersection of its elements using the notation:

`a & b`

Is there a specific method that I can implement to achieve this?  (I know that the individual elements need to implement the `__hash__` and `__eq__` methods)

I'm currently getting the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'PropArray' and 'PropArray'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to override:

```
def __and__(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
    """ Return self&value. """
    pass
```

in your class

Comment: Fantastic, that did the trick! Seems obvious in hindsight but my google-fu failed me.